# Change the way of price filter applied

Tags: magento-enterprise, collection, layered-navigation, product-collection

I have a custom stock status attribute with 4 options.

```
array(
    4 => 'In Stock',
    3 => 'Soon',
    2 => 'Out Of Stock',
    1 => 'Discontinued',
);
```

I want change the way of price filter in layered navigation applied. 
I want only products that has value "4" (In Stock) for stock status attribute displayed after applying price filter.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price::applyPriceRange` or (Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::applyPriceRange - one is a wrapper for the other). Both are called when applying the price filter to collection.
You can add in your new method an additional filter by your attribute.